# Formal algorithm to rewrite a grammar that has no left-recursion and shows right precedence

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ll-grammar

Is there any **formal algorithm** or **steps** to rewrite a grammar that has no left-recursion and shows right precedence. Such as that simple algorithm for eliminating left recursion described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion)

For example, given the following algorithm:

```
1 <goal> ::= <expr>$
2 <expr> ::= <expr><op><expr>
3           | num
4           | id
5 <op>   ::= +
6           |-
7           |*
8           |/
```

The desired output should be:

```
1. <expr> ::= <term><expr'>
2. <expr'> ::= +<term><expr'>
3.           | epsilon
4.           | -<term><expr'>
5. <term>  ::= <factor><term'>
6. <term'> ::= *<factor><term'>
7.           | epsilon
8.           | /<factor><term'>
```

Comment: How would this hypothetical algorithm know from your input what the desired operator precedence is?

Comment: oh. i forgot to say. we should define some precedence before